# How can I call qtip by clicking in such Jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm trying to join those 2 codes, but I kind of confused with jquery and qtip selector. Any tips?

```
<a href="#" class="linkClass">link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="linkClass">link 2</a>

$("body").on("click", "a.linkClass", function () {

});

and

        $('?').qtip({
            content: 'Hello 2nd Test',
            show: 'click',
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct use of click event for the show option.  You don't need the click handler for the link before it.

```
$('.linkClass').qtip({
    content: 'Hello 2nd Test',
    show: { when: { event: 'click' } }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, I'm having issues to make qtip work with jquery 1.9, I will test it soon

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.linkClass", function () {
     $(this).qtip({
        content: 'Hello 2nd Test',
        show: 'click',
     });
});
```